# Supporters In The Lead

Tags: idioms

I have a question about "in the lead" [here](http://www.northcarolina.statenews.net/index.php/sid/225817275):

> On Wednesday, campaigners were making last-minute pitches as polls suggested that ***pro-union supporters were narrowly in the lead*** despite a recent surge for the independence camp.

(BACKGROUND INFO:  For the Scotland independence referandum, pro-union people want "no" votes, independence people want "yes" votes.)

It is the number of possible no votes that was in the lead, not the pro-union supporters.  The pro-union supporters are simply trying to increase the number of no votes. So, could the phrase "**pro-union supporters** *were narrowly in the lead*" be wrong?  Would replacing that phrase with "**the no-votes** *were narrowly in the lead*" be better?

Comment: Can you explain your concern more clearly? What change would you suggest to "*pro-union supporters were narrowly in the lead*"?

Comment: @apsillers Even I got mixed up about which people are for the "yes" and "no" votes.  I've edited my question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You could, but a statement including *the no-votes* by itself would be meaningless. The meaning is in what outcome the no votes reflect. Since the no votes are backed by the "pro-union supporters", its more relevant in a news story to say the connection. Sometimes there is a short attention span.

Answer (score 1):

No, it would not be better to say that "the yes votes were narrowly in the lead".

The *lead* is not a quantity but a position. In a contest of any sort the *lead* is held by one of the competitors. For instance:

> Coming out of the turn Man o' War was in the lead by a length and a half. *In English we do not say that the number of lengths Man o' War had covered was in the lead over the number of lengths covered by other horses.*
>
> With nine games to play the Cardinals hold a two-and-a-half game lead over the Pirates. *In English we do not say that the number of games won by the Cardinals is in the lead over the number of games won by the Pirates*.

Likewise,

> On Wednesday, pro-union supporters were narrowly in the lead. *In English we do not say that the number of votes likely to accrue to supporters of union was in the lead over the number of votes likely to accrue to supporters of independence.*

The distance covered, the number of games won, the quantity of votes earned do not ‘*lead*’, they are not ‘in the *lead*’; they are merely **measures** of a *lead* which is held by a competitor.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement about what the pro-union supporters are trying to do is wrong.
They are not trying to *increase the number of yes votes*; they are trying to *have enough yes votes that the proposal passes.*  If the number of yes votes is larger than the number of no votes by any amount, the pro-union side achieves their goal; that is, they win.  If the vote count stands at 1000 yes to 999 no, the pro-union side wins.

The polls show that the pro-union side has a small numerical advantage in the estimated vote counts (that is, slightly more people will vote yes than no), so claiming that "pro-union supporters were narrowly in the lead" is a perfectly normal and valid thing to write.

(Well, other than the nitpick that "pro-union supporters" is redundant; it should be the "pro-union side" or the "union supporters".)

Comment: Even I got mixed up about which people are for the "yes" and "no" votes.  I've edited my question.  Sorry for the confusion.